# optional JAXB xml attribute while marshalling

Tags: jaxb, xml-attribute

When I marshal java object using JAXB I am getting below xml element

```
<error line="12" column="" message="test" />
```

But I want xml as below

```
<error line="12" message="test" />
```

If column value is empty then I need to get the xml as shown above otherwise I need to get the column attribute in the element.

Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An attribute will only be marshalled out with an empty `String` value if the corresponding field/property contains a empty `String` value.  If the value is null the attribute will not be marshalled.

**Root**

```java
package forum13218462;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    @XmlAttribute
    String attributeNull;

    @XmlAttribute
    String attributeEmpty;

    @XmlAttribute(required=true)
    String attributeNullRequired;

}
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum13218462;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Root root = new Root();
        root.attributeNull = null;
        root.attributeEmpty = "";
        root.attributeNullRequired = null;

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root attributeEmpty=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. How to do the same thing in case of primitive types (like int)?

Comment: @Suresh - You mean for `int` you're getting `foo="0"`? You could change the field/property to be of `Integer` instead.  Then when it has a null value it won't write the attribute.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan, can you tell how to construct xsd to have primitive wrapper instead of primitive type in generated from it class? I have this: <xs:attribute name="fromFraction" type="xs:float" use="optional" default="0.0"/> and it generates fromFraction field as float, and then I can't get rid of it in result XML.