# XML element Annotation in Java

Tags: java, xml, annotations

I have question about how to add additional attributes to a root tag of an xml-structure.

let say this is my java-class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "myRoot")
@XmlType(name = "myType")
public class A implements B {

    @CoId
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

and I want as result an output which can be like this below:

```
"<myRoot newAttribute="something">
<id>111</id>
</myRoot>"
```

I mean the attribute newAttribute should be dynamically added. What is the annotation for this, how should I adapt my class here?

Comment: You want to inject   newAttribute="something" in your XML serialization right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [optional JAXB xml attribute while marshalling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218462/optional-jaxb-xml-attribute-while-marshalling)